# Is there easy way to build privileges and users in Access forms project?

Tags: ms-access

I'm building Access forms, I need to implement privileges for users, is there an easy way to achieve this in Access with out writing too many VBA ?

- I'm using Access 2013
- .mdb files
- Access database.

Comment: What version of Access are you using? Are you using .mdb files or .accdb files? What back end are you using, Access or SQL? Difficult to answer without this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an .mdb file, you can secure your database using user-level security. There's plenty of information available about how to implement it, the best place to start is to search the help file for "user-level security".

Assuming you've already created your .mdb, click on the File tab, then go to the Info section. Click on  Users and Permissions and then "User Level Security Wizard". This will guide you through setting up a new workgroup file (.mdw) and assigning permissions.

It is my recommendation that you focus on securing your tables first. Although you can secure your forms, they won't be of any use to anyone if they can't get to the data they display. When setting up security, always try to work with groups - don't assign permissions to individual users, or you'll just create a lot of work for yourself.

You need to be aware that MS are discouraging the use of .mdb files now - the default format is .accdb, and they recommend using SQL Server Express for data storage, which provides its own security. Access 2013 will still support .mdb's, but they are treated like second-class citizens!